# Parsing a simple XML from string in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I have a simple XML and I need to get the **first**  '*id*' from puid-list. I found lots of examples but none of them quite do that because of the namespace. How do get the **id** out as an *NSString*?

**PS:** I'm on a Mac.

```
<genpuid songs="1" xmlns:mip="http://musicip.com/ns/mip-1.0#">
  <track file="/htdocs/test.mp3" puid="0c9f2f0e-e72a-c461-9b9a-e18e8964ca20">
    <puid-list>
      <puid id="0c9f2f0e-e72a-c461-9b9a-e18e8964ca20"/>
    </puid-list>
  </track>
</genpuid>
```

Comment: Are you on a Mac or iPhone?  iPhones only have NSXMLParser, but Macs have NSXMLDocument (which supports XPath).  Also, although you have a namespace, it is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `NSXMLParser`. Create an instance in your code and tell it to parse:

```
NSData * XMLData = [myXMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:XMLData];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES]; // if you need to
[parser parse]; // start parsing
```

then you need to implement the methods of `NSXMLParserDelegate` to get callbacks during parsing:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    /* handle namespaces here if you want */

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"puid"]){
         NSString * ID = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
         // use ID string, or store it in an ivar so you can access it somewhere else
    }
}
```

Notes on handling namespaces:

If the namespaces are set, `elementName` is the qualified name, so could have prefix (e.g. `mip:puid`) If you're on the Mac, `NSXMLNode` has to convenience class methods, `localNameForName:` and `prefixForName:` to get the two parts of the string.

Also, You might want the `NXXMLParser` delegate methods `parser:didStartMappingPrefix:toURI:` and `parser:didEndMappingPrefix:`.

Note that names returned by `NSXMLParser` are exactly those from the string (regarding whether they're prefixed). So it's rare for the attribute to be named `mip:id`, but if you want to be robust, you need to check for this as well.