# Reading and parsing an XML file from a Cocoa app

Tags: xml, cocoa, macos

Is there a standard way to load, read and parse an XML file from Cocoa?

I followed the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946254/parsing-a-simple-xml-from-string-in-cocoa) question but I can't quite get it, I am getting all confused. I'm a C programmer and obj-c is not my strong point. The idea is to parse the XML file and load the data into several objects on the GUI.

Thank you for the help.

EDIT

This is an example of the XML I need to parse. I need a full example of how to do this since all the bit and pieces of examples that I found are taking me nowhere. Thank you, I appreciate the help.

```
<Project Name="Accountant">
    <Name>
        Some Name
    </Name>

    <Year>
        2011
    </Year>

    <ApplicationStatus>
        In Progress
    </ApplicationStatus>

    <OutputDir>
        /SomePath/To/a/FileName
    </OutputDir>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSXMLParser` parse some XML Data in cooperation with its delegate. You first alloc/init the parser, giving it either directly `NSData` object (containing your XML Data), or a URL where it can retrieve the XML Data to parse.
Then you give the parser a reference to the delegate by setting its `delegate` property, and finally ask the parser to parse the data.

This is described in [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i).

To be short, `NSXMLParser` is object that do parse the data, but you won't obtain any elements or attributes from it.
Instead, the parser tells its delegate when it finds something, and the delegate can then handle the element or attribute.  That also means you don't have to wait for the parser to finish its job, you just tell it to begin parsing.
So in this schema, the big job is to implement `NSXMLParser`'s delegate methods depending on what you want to do with the XML.

If you need detailed informations about each classes you can also visit :

[NSXMLParser Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
[NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you. There's a lot of good information here and it clarifies a lot, however it also confuses me even further. As I said, my obj-c is not very good (I'm a C programmer). I can go and do this the hard way by writing C code and parse it manually but if I could get an example of how to load the file (i guess fopen()?) parse it and get the data I need it'd be great. None of these links provide an example. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jessica - to be honest, I think your best (and simplest) bet is to deals with objects directly. I'm not a professional C programmer you know, but everything of C can be done in an Objective C program.

Comment: @Jessica - I know you can construct a `NSString` from a C string (`-(id)initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;`), and then you can get `NSData` object from it, and give that to the parser.

Comment: @Jessica - to load the file, simply give the URL to the `NSXMLParser` initializer... the URL can be the one of a file in the device as well.

Comment: @Jessica - Check [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle) or [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=499671).

Comment: thank you. let me check all that. I still do not know how to pass to the parser the XML key names that I expect, furthermore if I convert the XML to a string how do I send this to an XML parser. In any case let me check those links

Comment: @Jessica - In case you got `NSString` object containing the XML, you need to get `NSData` instance from it : `NSData *d = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`, then instanciate the parser : `NSXMLParser *p = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:d];`.

Comment: Yeah. I still have no idea how to do it. In the example you pointed 'parseXMLFileAtURL' creates a bunch of stuff, calls a bunch of other, what, methods? and that it's what happens with the XML? how do I parse it? And why the empty functions at the end. Sorry but to me it does not make any sense...

Comment: @Jessica - anyway you instanciate the parser, its delegate gets notified of each XML element parsed, that's where you act. If that element is interesting do something, else do nothing.

Comment: @Jessica let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1848/discussion-between-vince-and-jessica)

Comment: Thank you. I did understand that one (pass the NSData to the XML parser) but then what? I am going to have to find a full example, not bits and chunks since I can't put it together.