# DIsplaying a tumbnail image from an RSS feed into tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss, thumbnails

I am creating an RSS feed app for work and I pretty much have most done except for one thing, getting the image for each article to load into the thumbnail UIImage View. I've searched around the web for some answers but still havent figured it out after a few days. Here is the code I have so far related to images :

In my MWFeedParser.m class :

```
else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/media:thumbnail"])
{
    if ([currentElementAttributes objectForKey:@"url"])
        {
            item.thumbnailURL = [currentElementAttributes valueForKey:@"url"];
                            processed = YES;
        } 
}
```

In my RSSMaster.m class :

```
 NSString *imageURLstr = item.thumbnailURL ? item.thumbnailURL : @"";
```

In my RSSResults.m class:

```
NSLog(@"IMAGE URL: %@", imageURLstr);

if (![imageURLstr isEqualToString:@""]) { 
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLstr];

//image download
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(q, ^{
/* Fetch the image from the server... */
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
/* This is the main thread again, where we set the tableView's image to
be what we just fetched. */
cell.thumbnail.image = img;
        });
    });
}
```

The image starts in the code at src= and is follwed by the artcile description. So my question is, how do I code my project so that the individual image link for each article gets pulled into my thumnail UIImage view in my tableView cells?

Any kind of detailed help would be greatly appreciated so that I can finally be done with this, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use an XML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946254/parsing-a-simple-xml-from-string-in-cocoa), or you can treat it as `NSString` and extract the `src` attribute like this :

```
NSString *imageURLstr=item.summary;
imgURL = [imgURL substringToIndex:[imgURL rangeOfString:@"alt="].location-2];
imgURL = [imgURL substringFromIndex:[imgURL rangeOfString:@"src="].location+[@"src=" length]+1];

NSLog(@"src: %@",imgURL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I implemented it and it worked but now it's just showing the same piture from one article for all the thumbnails in the cells. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Maybe because you get the content of the url just once and parse just the first image. If you sahre the code where you get the content of the RSSfeedit will be better for me to help.

Comment: Of course i can share it, thanks for the continued help. I created a repository for it on github so that you may see the whole project. The file specifically where i entered the code you gave me and where it is getting the rss feed link from is in "RSSReader/RSSReader/Classes/RSSMaster.m" 

Here is the link to the repository: 

https://github.com/cpoti24/RSSReader

Comment: Also, if you do have a mac and xcode feel free to download it and run the simulator if you're interested in that

Comment: @CS_Student I have updated my answer. You have copied the code without replacing the string with the item summary. you should get the description of each item and get the image. The text I used was just an example. Now just change `NSString *imageURLstr=item.summary;` I have tested the code and it works. If it's fine please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: It worked finally! Thank you for the great help! Upvoted and accepted as answer